# Laravel 5 Eloquent belongsTo() foreign key won't work

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5, belongs-to

I found out that naming of the column in Schema::create() can affect creating constrains, so it can't be found by Model in later queries.

Schema (simplefied):

```
Schema::create('page_elements', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('page_element_type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('page_element_type_id')->references('id')->on('page_element_types')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And when I call

```
PageElement::find(1)->first()->type()->get()
```

I get empty collection.

After changing this 2 lines in Shema (only change is `page_element_type_id` into `type_id`):

```
$table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('page_element_types')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');
```

I got the 1 element in collection, as it should.

Anyone knows if there is some naming issue or rule, regarding this columns with constrains?

EDID:
Declaration of type() in Model, as requested:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PageElementType');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you show your `type` function?

I would bet you did not use the second parameter to set the name of the column that has the foreign key, so change it to:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\YourModel', 'page_element_type_id');
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the [API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsTo) only, but I am wondering is there some rule or limitation regarding the name of the column. Because I think it is obvious that you are defining the foreign key using ->foreign() method, an than in object dump I see that he uses shorten name "type_id". Couldn't find anything about that automate naming...

Comment: I don't think there is. Is your model named `Type`?

Comment: Type model name is PageElementType

Comment: Then you have witnessed legit laravel sorcery.